# What is the wrong in 4th line in not if

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

What is the wrong in 4th line which is not if is saying syntax error

```rb
if user["passwordexpire"]
         execute 'Passwordexpire sudo login' do
             command "chage -I \-1 -m 0 -M 99999 -E \-1 #{user['id']}"
             not_if "grep -qs 'ls -1 | grep "^#{user['id']}"' /etc/shadow | grep 99999"
         end

     end
 end
```

It is showing syntax error

Comment: double quotes inside double quotes?

Comment: Switching on syntax highlighting here makes this visible as well :-p

Comment: Make this an answer

Comment: What is wrong can you correct me

Comment: not_if 'grep -qs 'ls -1 | grep "^#{user['id']}"' /etc/shadow | grep 99999'   also did not worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the inner double quotes somehow.

```
not_if "grep -qs 'ls -1 | grep \"^#{user['id']}\"' /etc/shadow | grep 99999"
```

Granted even with that change I have no idea what that command is supposed to mean so I suspect this won't work but that is at least valid Ruby code.